# Trying to generate a Shiny Web App but having issues with arg error

Tags: r, shiny

I have created the below Shiny web app in order to download currency data from Quandl and then plot the time series.

However, when I run the code, I get the error message: **'arg' must be NULL or a character vector**.

I have looked at previous answers, and often the issue seemed to be that the reactive expression was not defined properly. However, to my knowledge, all the relevant columns are nested within the fluidRow so I cannot tell what is causing this error.

Any advice appreciated.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Currency"),

  fluidRow(
    column(3, 
       selectInput("currencypairs", 
                          h3("Currency Pairs"), 
                          choices = c("EUR/USD" = "FRED/DEXUSEU", 
                                         "USD/GBP" = "FRED/DEXUSUK", 
                                         "USD/AUD" = "FRED/DEXUSAL"),
                          selected = "EUR/USD")),
    column(3, 
       dateInput("start_date", 
                 h3("Start Date"), 
                 value = "2014-01-01")),
    column(3, 
       dateInput("end_date", 
                 h3("End Date"), 
                 value = "2017-01-01"))   
  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated output
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("CurrencyOutput")
  )
 )
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
require(Quandl)

# Shiny Application
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$CurrencyOutput <- renderPlot({

    currency = Quandl(input$currencypairs, 
input$start_date,input$end_date,type="xts")
    currencydf<-data.frame(currency)
    plot(currencydf$currency,type='l',col="blue")
  })

})
```

Comment: can you manually run the code inside the renderPlot and check for errors? Failing that, `options(error=traceback)` may help.

Comment: I did that. Had to modify the code to include the actual inputs, but it worked fine.

Comment: Looks like the codes you are requesting passes empty value. I get the error, saying `"You have submitted an incorrect Quandl code.` when I submit the currency code

Comment: Well, it worked fine for me. This is the code I used:     currency = Quandl("FRED/DEXUSAL",start_date="2015-01-01",end_date="2016-01-01",type="xts")
    currencydf<-data.frame(currency)
    plot(currencydf$currency,type='l',col="blue")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code and found a solution. You need to put start_date and end_date instead your input directly, so the code looks like:

`currency = Quandl(input$currencypairs, start_date=input$start_date, end_date=input$end_date, type="xts")`

I hope it helps